# Entity object not updating

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I created a static class that I want to use in various projects. I am trying to make this as independent as I can but it's not updating and I'm getting no error messages. I am using .Net Framework 4.0 client.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace SSS.ServicesConfig.data
{
  public partial class GlobalSetting
  {

    public static GlobalSetting GetGlobalSetting()
    {
      try
      {
        using (var context = new SuburbanEntities())
        {
          return (from gs in context.GlobalSettings
                  select gs).FirstOrDefault();
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Logging.Log("An error occurred.", "GetGlobalSetting", Apps.ServicesConfig, ex);
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Unable to retrieve data: [{0}].", ex.Message));
      }
    }

    public static void SaveGlobalSettings(GlobalSetting globalSetting)
    {
      using (var context = new SuburbanEntities())
      {
        context.Attach(globalSetting);
        context.SaveChanges();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is the attach not done the right way? If not, how should I be saving it when it comes back in?

Comment: Entity Framework has its own version. Take a look at the DLL under References and post the version.

Comment: You might consider upgrading, EF 6 is current. I think VS2010 came with EF 4.0 out of the box, it was quickly followed by 4.1, 4.3 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, I suggest you try removing the using statement in both methods and declare the context in this manner or better still a private varialbe to hold the local context variable.

```
     var context = new SuburbanEntities())
     context.Attach(globalSetting);
     context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: @ErocM This can't make any difference. With or without the `using` the context object is out of scope after the `SaveGlobalSettings` method has ended. There must be something else you changed at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the state to modified:

```
  context.Attach(globalSetting);
  context.Entry(globalSetting).State = EntityState.Modified;
  context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: same as the other answer, cannot find Entry...? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First of all, when asking about a fast-changing tech like EF: always mention the version(s). You should still do that for this question.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you're in the `ObjectContext` API, so the way to mark an entity as changed is:

```
context.ObjectStateManager
       .ChangeObjectState(globalSetting, EntityState.Modified);
```

after you attached the object to the context.

Answer (score 0):

must mark it modified, try

```
context.Attach(globalSetting);
var gs = context.Entry(globalSetting);
gs.State = EntityState.Modified;
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I've not used Entry before but it says 'cannot resolve symbol Entry'. I am using .Net 4.0 client profile. Would that matter?

Comment: it's part of EF 4.1, try this instead to mark it modified context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(globalSettings, EntityState.Modified);

Comment: Cannot access non static content EntityState.Modified